# Check if object got at least specified properties

Tags: typescript

I have a function that send an object that got `{ name: { value: string }, + some unknown property }`, how can I type my parameter to accept this object if he got at least { name: { value: string } } ?

Example:

```
// Working but is there a specific type to explicitly do this without [x:string]: any ?
const sortNameV2 = (array: Array<{ name: { value: string }, [x:string]: any }>, sortOrder: 'ASC' | 'DESC') => {
  return [...array]
    .sort((a, b) => 
      a.name.value.localeCompare(b.name.value)
    )
}

sortNameV2([{ name: { value: 'titi'}, id: 1 }], 'ASC')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a generic type argument using `extends`:

```typescript
// Working but is there a specific type to explicitly do this without [x:string]: any ?
const sortNameV2 = <ElementType extends { name: { value: string } }>(array: Array<ElementType>, sortOrder: 'ASC' | 'DESC') => {
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  return [...array]
    .sort((a, b) => 
      a.name.value.localeCompare(b.name.value)
    )
}

sortNameV2([{ name: { value: 'titi'}, id: 1 }], 'ASC')
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUHsCcGsEsB2BzUAjArgF1PAzqFgBYCm0JoAhqHgA4kDG8AZvA4QJ72GSgkAetADZt4WIR1AATXsXygA7mKKRsoANr8AXHizQkyALpaqiSQH4AUA0iJdNGFgBylALYkAagCZQAXlAAPACiQiTuiFgAKlwUAlgkiFIEAN6giG4kJqkAbpRCGJk0egagAL5lAHwAFJTQ0JQcJgCCdQ3BoeFRMRUANA7QWADy0FJkJgDkTQDKAMLjoAA+oOMAIkGz4wCUfhWgyZagoORYGNCIGgB0V7X1HIYHh6AXeI5VNX1o2767D49UF+l3BdcvkSBchJAGHkSDNIK5aLUSFU0ACMsC8gVNr9QFjSpZLC8Bi53N4qupUoDCjkMYVxlgxPBxqU+vApCYAIxlQx9SYbTZAA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's the kind of tricks I was looking for. Can you explain me why is this working ? I know about generics but I've never used it like that before

Comment: @NicolasMenettrier - The only reason your original code was complaining was that you were passing an object literal to the function, and TypeScript has a special "excess property check" it does when you're assigning an object literal to something (which you effectively are with a function argument -- you're assigning the argument to the function's parameter): It figures if you're using an object literal, you probably meant to *only* give the properties the type defines, not "excess" ones. (If you'd created the object and assigned it to a variable, then passed variable into the function, ...

Comment: ... you wouldn't get the error because excess property checks don't apply.) Sometimes you want those "excess" properties, though. By doing it indirectly through a generic type parameter, we aren't specifying a concrete type for the parameter, we're just saying "any type that has *at least* these properties." So TypeScript doesn't apply the excess property check.

Answer (score 1):

Not answering your question directly.

Working with generics might get confusing. My suggestion is that you do not create a function that sorts the array but rather just the comparer. Maybe it would be more reusable, because it allows the user to decide whether to create a copy or to sort in place. Also you could wrap it in a curried function that gets passed a sort order.

```
type ItemWithName = { name: { value: string }}

const sortNameComparer(order: 'ASC' | 'DESC' = 'ASC') {
   return (a: ItemWithName, b: ItemWithName) => 
        a.name.value.localeCompare(b.name.value) * (
           order === 'ASC' ? 1 : -1
        )
}

// usage

[{ name: { value: 'titi'}, id: 1 }].sort(sortNameComparer('ASC'))
```